# Change style when checkbox is checked - Vue

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I have a form with some checkboxes for each day of the week, what I want to do is that when the checkbox is clicked, it turns blue in the background and the white letters.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {

  },
  methods: {

  }
})
```

```css
.label-checkbox {
  margin-right: 0.87rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  border: 1px solid #4273DE;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #4273DE;
}

.check-day {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <label class="label-checkbox" for="monday">
    <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="monday" value="monday" />
    Mon
  </label>
  <label class="label-checkbox" for="tuesday">
    <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="tuesday" value="tuesday" />
    Tues
  </label>
  <label class="label-checkbox" for="wednesday">
    <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="wednesday" value="wednesday" />
    Wed
  </label>
  <label class="label-checkbox" for="thursday">
    <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="thursday" value="thursday" />
    Thu
  </label>
  <label class="label-checkbox" for="friday">
    <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="friday" value="friday" />
    Fri
  </label>
  <label class="label-checkbox" for="saturday">
    <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="saturday" value="saturday" />
    Sat
  </label>
  <label class="label-checkbox" for="sunday">
    <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="sunday" value="sunday" />
    Sun
  </label>
</div>
```

When selecting the day, I would like it to look like the following image:

[image: Desired result]

Help me please.

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bardalesj/q7usmayh/1/

Comment: look into [Vue Guide: classes and styles binding](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) and [Vue Guide: Form Input Binding](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) then you will know how to reach the goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `v-model` the checkboxes to their own data property and use these properties to toggle a class binding:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    days: [
      { title: 'Monday' },
      { title: 'Tuesday' },
      { title: 'Wednesday' },
      { title: 'Thursday' },
      { title: 'Friday' },
      { title: 'Saturday' },
      { title: 'Sunday' },
    ]
  },
})
```

```css
.label-checkbox {
  margin-right: 0.87rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  border: 1px solid #4273DE;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #4273DE;
}

.check-day {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}

.checked {
  background: #4273DE;
  color: #fff;
}

.checked::before {
  content: "✔";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <label v-for="day in days" :key="day.title" class="label-checkbox" :class="{ 'checked': day.checked }" :for="day.title.toLowerCase()">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="day.checked" class="check-day" :id="day.title.toLowerCase()" :value="day.title" />
    {{ day.title }}
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: One of the benefits of components, encapsulation, and OOP in general is not repeating yourself.  This code would be considered bad practice for being unnecessarily verbose by not using a collection (array/object) and a `v-for`.

Comment: for best practice, we should use `data () {return {}}` instead of `data: {}`

Comment: @Sphinx [This is only a concern with reusable components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function)